# Plsql: How to write this trigger using statement level trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have been trying to solve this problem since yesterday but I can't figure out how to write a working statement level trigger that does this task.

Here's the question:

Implement and comprehensively test a statement trigger that verifies the
following consistency constraint.

“A position cannot need more than 4 skills”.

When ready save your CREATE TRIGGER statement and all SQL statements that
comprehensively test a trigger in a script solution3.sql. Comprehensive testing means that the trigger must reject SQL statements that violate the consistency constraint and accept SQL statements that do not violate the consistency constraint. It is a part of your task to find what SQL statements should be tested. Whenever SQL statement violates the consistency constraint a trigger must return ORA-… error message. Use a procedure RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR to return ORA-… error message. If SQL statement does not violate the consistency constraint then a trigger must return no
messages.

Here are the database files if you want to give this probelm a try: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4dyemye2bpq5hv4/AAAEAmTDELHcgFFhpfRrqHtDa?dl=0

The code that I have written gives me error that new and old can't be used on table level triggers and I think this function will work if I make it row level trigger but I need it to work as statement trigger. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
create or replace trigger checkskillnum
before insert or update of pnumber on sneeded
declare
skillnum number;
begin
select count(*) into skillnum from sneeded where sneeded.pnumber = :new.pnumber;
if skillnum > 3 then
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20030,'A position does not need more than 4 skills');
end if;
end;
/
```

The result should allow insert or update to only those statements where skillnum is less than 4.
But right now it complies with error: new and old can't be used on table level triggers.

NEW SOLUTION:

Table SNEEDED:
The select statement has the first result which is 4 and the trigger only checks that result even if the pnumber is different.

```
SQL> select pnumber, count(*) as SKILL_COUNT
  2                   from sneeded
  3                   group by pnumber
  4                   order by COUNT(*) DESC
  5  ;

   PNUMBER SKILL_COUNT
---------- -----------
         1           4
         2           3
         3           3
         7           3
         5           3
         6           1
         4           1

7 rows selected.
```

Error in the new solution:

```
SQL> insert into sneeded values(1,'fishing',7);
insert into sneeded values(1,'fishing',7)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20030: A position does not need more than 4 skills
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.CHECKSKILLNUM", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.CHECKSKILLNUM'


SQL> insert into sneeded values(2,'fishing',7);
insert into sneeded values(2,'fishing',7)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20030: A position does not need more than 4 skills
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.CHECKSKILLNUM", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.CHECKSKILLNUM'


SQL> insert into sneeded values(4,'fishing',7);
insert into sneeded values(4,'fishing',7)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20030: A position does not need more than 4 skills
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.CHECKSKILLNUM", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.CHECKSKILLNUM'
```

Comment: Please post your code so people can see what you're running.

Comment: All the code is available above. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I for one can't download code from dropbox, I'm sure others are in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

A statement trigger (one which doesn't have `FOR EACH ROW`) cannot use `:OLD` and `:NEW` because it doesn't have access to the row values. But you don't really need them in this case - you just need to Think Differently.

What you care about is - after the statement executes, are there any people with more than three skills? So you need to figure out how to find that bit of information.

The following should do it for you:

```
create or replace trigger checkskillnum
  before insert or update on sneeded
begin
  FOR aRow IN (select pnumber, count(*) as SKILL_COUNT
                 from sneeded 
                 group by pnumber
                 order by COUNT(*) DESC)
  LOOP
    IF aRow.SKILL_COUNT > 3 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20030, 'A position does not need more than 4 skills');
    END IF;

    EXIT;    -- The first row will have the highest SKILL_COUNT, so only need to  
  END LOOP;  -- check the first row.
end CHECKSKILLNUM;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this one looks much better than my trigger and It complies without error but it doesn't work the way it should. This trigger only checks the highest skill_count which is for only pnumber = 1. But if I try to insert a skill for other pnumber where skill_count is less than 3 it still gets triggered. I want the trigger to check skill_count for a particular pnumber (which is being inserted or updated).

Comment: If the first row in the query above does not exceed 3, then you know *all* the rows in the table meet your criteria, including the one just inserted/updated.

Comment: Sorry, I am still clueless. I have added the error in the answer above.

Comment: Also added the sneeded table so you can see whats causing the problem

Comment: If you want to check the specific `pnumber` being changed you'd need to use a row trigger - but your assignment specifically requires that you use a statement trigger where you don't have that information available.